# "say I" or "say me"?

Tags: subjects

> 1. "I love you," say I.
> 2. "I love you," say me.
> 3. "I love you," says I.
> 4. "I love you," says me.

Which is correct? I'm thinking that it should be the first one, since it's "I say 'I love you.'"

Comment: You are correct. It is impossible to imagine any native speaker using 2. "Says I" may be encountered in dialect, particularly in a narrative. *Says me* MIGHT occur in response to the belligerent question "Says who?", (="I said it; ya wanna make somethin of it?"), but not in this context.

Comment: @StoneyB 1 is not correct, it should be 3. Or it could be "'I love you' *I say*"

Comment: @DJ McMayhem: I think ***sez I*** is archaic/dialectal (regardless of how you spell it). The past tense version *(ILY, said I)* is unexceptional in formal/dated writing, where I've no doubt the "correct" present tense version would be ***say** I* - but all variants are going to come across as somewhat strange, since we don't normally use these "inverted" forms in speech anyway.

Comment: I would never say any of these... says I.

Answer (score 1):

When you are the subject of a sentence, you use "I". For example:

> *I* told her I wouldn't stand for this anymore.

In that sentence, *I* is the subject, because you are the one doing the talking. When you are the object of a sentence, you should use "me". For example

> She told *me* she wouldn't stand for this anymore.

In that sentence, *she* is the subject, since she is the one doing the talking, and *me* is the object, because you are the one being talked to.

In your sentence, you are the one doing the talking, so "I" should be the subject. So we can narrow it down to 1 or 3. 1 and 3 both sound strange to my ear. I *thought* that "says I" is correct (even though it sounds strange), but according to StoneyB, FumbleFingers, and some quick googling, it should be "say I." (You learn something new everyday!) However, if you want it to sound more natural, I would recommend inverting the word order, and saying either

> "I love you" I said. (past tense)

or

> "I love you" I say. (present tense)